# Execute CMD Command from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, shell, cmd, command, command-line-interface

Hi I want to start a program from my vb.net app.

The problem I have, are spaces in the commant. 
My code looks like this :

```
Dim p As New Process
Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
execute = generateStatement(project)
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
pi.UseShellExecute = False
pi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
pi.Arguments = "/K " + execute
p.StartInfo = pi
p.Start()
```

> execute = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE" 
>   cmd Output =  'C:\Program' is not reconized as internal or external command

then I tried to put Quotes ( add Char 34 ) befor and afer the string like this :

> execute = ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE""

still same cmd output. 
So i tried the command via Shell, still same problem.

Can someone tell me how I can pass a consol command with spaces in it ? 
Change dir is no option, I have to put some more directories in the command.

Comment: Consider using `System.Management.Automation` //used for powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track: To escape quote in the argument, you can use quotes. But, you must also put your escaped quoted string in a string so actually, you end up with three quotes where you define execute.

```
execute = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE"""
```

quote 1: start string

quote 2: escape quote

quote 3: the quote

Or, escape it when you build pi.arguments:

```
pi.Arguments = "/K " + """" + execute """"
```

quote 1: start string

quote 2: escape

quote 3: the quote character

quote 4: end string

Comment: Thank you. this worked for me. 
Adding three qoutes to the string was not on my list . ;)